# postfix: Show destination port for incoming connection in the logs

Tags: postfix, smtp

I have Postfix listening on several ports for incoming mail.  E.g. ports 25 and 587.  I'd like to see in the logs the destination port of each incoming connection.

Answer (score 2):

Use `syslog_name` in the smtpd options in `/etc/postfix/master.cf`.  This changes the name of the process in the standard-format log line.  The default is `postfix/smtpd`.  So to change it for the `submission` line (port 587), add this to the options:

```
-o syslog_name=postfix-submission
```

Note that the default process name is kept as a prefix.  Don't include "/smtpd" because this is added automatically.

Example default log line:

```
Sep 28 01:22:28 XXXXXX postfix/smtpd[11737]: connect from unknown[203.194.109.130]
```

Example "augmented" log line:

```
Sep 28 01:22:28 XXXXXX postfix-submission/smtpd[11737]: connect from unknown[203.194.109.130]
```

**Warning**: Do not change this option in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`, or it will change the output for all of Postfix's listening ports.