# Can postfix log source ports for inbound SMTP connections?

Tags: postfix

At the moment, postfix logs inbound connections like this:

```
May  4 11:15:01 hostname postfix/smtpd[161025]: connect from unknown[192.0.2.1]
```

This isn't enough information for hosting providers to respond to abuse reports where they use CGNAT.  They need the source port to identify the offending customer.

Is there any way to make postfix log the source port?  Something like this would be ideal:

```
May  4 11:15:01 hostname postfix/smtpd[161025]: connect from unknown[192.0.2.1:12345]
```

Comment: Related question about **destination ports**: https://serverfault.com/questions/725122/postfix-show-destination-port-for-incoming-connection-in-the-logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just set `smtpd_client_port_logging` to `yes`.

> **smtpd_client_port_logging (default: no)**
>
> Enable logging of the remote SMTP client port in addition to the hostname and IP address. The logging format is "host[address]:port".
>
> This feature is available in Postfix 2.5 and later.
>
> -- [man 5 postconf](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_client_port_logging)

Note that the format does not quite match your example, **it will place the port after the brackets:** `unknown[192.0.2.1]:12345`

Beware of log aggregation and **analysis tools that might need their regex patterns adjusted** to correctly parse the changed format - notably utilities like *fail2ban* might no longer detect the relevant log lines.

Comment: Perfect, and works like a charm.  Thanks!